# Visual has exceeded the available resources. Tips on how to streamline / better understand limitations?

Tags: powerbi

OK, so I have a relatively complex report that works well on the desktop app but is bombing out on the web portal.  Apparently, it is requesting 1048584KB which is just shy of the 1048576KB limit.

This report is a matrix, built as follows:

[image]

It is connected to two primary data sources, along with some tertiary feeds and helper tables.  One of these is a sales detail table that is a CSV 887MB in size.  The other is a purchasing detail table that is an XLS 26MB in size.

I have filtered out portions of the sales table (by date) in the Edit Queries screen.  I have also filtered out specific item divisions in the matrix.  It is the second step that was allowing this visual to function previously (took out a few not-needed divisions and it started working again, but now this no longer seems to work).

I would like to not just get a quick answer here, but also to better understand how Power BI is allocating the memory and how I can streamline.  The rest of the report is using the same data but this is the only visual that fails to load (aside from some tables that are on a line-level and are intended to be filtered down via slicers prior to displaying information).  Will add that there are some relatively complex measures that are firing on this visual and not used anywhere else, presuming this has a lot to do with memory demands...right?